# Best practices in context of asynchronous Javascript when calling functions in functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to call two functions and pass the output of the first function as a parameter into the second.

Function 1:

```
module.exports.getAllStatisticsByUserId = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, (err, user) =>{
        if(err)
        throw err;
        if(user)
        callback(null, user.statistics);

    });
}
```

Function 2:

```
module.exports.getGameByStatisticsId = function(id, callback){

    Statistics.findById(id, (err, statistics) =>{
        if(err)
        throw err;
        if(statistics)
        callback(null, statistics.game);
    });
};
```

I am trying to execute the second method by passing the output of the first method as a parameter but the asynchronous nature of javascript is messing it up. I have tried implementing promises to no avail.

Can anyone suggest some good javascript practices to deal with calling functions asynchronously when they need each other? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah... you said it yourself, though, unfortunately: I would recommend using promises. This tutorial was immensely helpful for me: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Comment: Instead of `throw err;` you need to `callback(err);`

Comment: Thanks for the article and tip !

Comment: There is no output of the first method.  All it does is initiate a request.  When that request has been retrieved, it has the option of calling a callback function which has access to the results.  So the code you want to execute "on" the results had better be in that callback or called from within that callback.

Comment: Best practises? Use promises. Don't use `throw` in asynchronous callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing [the issue I mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014057/best-practices-in-context-of-asynchronous-javascript-when-calling-functions-in-f#comment85032983_49014057), you can call them in sequence like this:

```
module.exports.getAllStatisticsByUserId = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, (err, user) =>{
        if(err) callback(err);
        if(user) callback(null, user.statistics);
    });
};

module.exports.getGameByStatisticsId = function(id, callback){
    Statistics.findById(id, (err, statistics) =>{
        if(err) callback(err);
        if(statistics) callback(null, statistics.game);
    });
};
```

```
someService.getAllStatisticsByUserId(id, (err, statistics) => {
  if (err || !statistics) {
    // handle error
    return;
  }

  someService.getGameByStatisticsId(statistics.id, (err, game) => {
    if (err || !game) {
      // handle error
      return;
    }

    // handle game
  });
});
```

However, as noted [in Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> When a `callback` function is not passed, an instance of Query is returned, which provides a special query builder interface.
>   A Query has a `.then()` function, and thus can be used as a promise.

So you can simply rewrite the calls like this:

```
someService.getAllStatisticsByUserId(id).then(statistics =>
  someService.getGameByStatisticsId(statistics.id)
).then(game => {
  // handle game
}).catch(err => {
  // handle error
});
```

or convert it into an `async/await` function:

```
async function getGameByUserId(id) {
  try {
    const statistics = await someService.getAllStatisticsByUserId(id);
    const game = await someService.getGameByStatisticsId(statistics.id);

    // handle game
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Note that an `async` function always returns a `Promise`, so you must `await` it or chain it with a `.then()` to ensure completion of the query and resolve the returned value, if any.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to write:

```
getAllStatisticsByUserId("me", (err, stats) => {
  getGameByStatisticsId(stats.id, (err, game) => {
    console.log(game);
  });
});
```

Here's how it would look if these functions returned promises instead.

```
getAllStatisticsByUserId("me")
  .then(stats => getGameByStatisticsId(stats.id))
  .then(game => console.log(game))
```

Even better, if you're able to use a version of Node that supports `async/await` then you could write.

```
let stats = await getAllStatisticsByUserId("me");
let game = await getGameByStatisticsId(stats.id);
console.log(game);
```

This would mean slightly rewriting the original functions (unless `User.findById` and `Statistics.findById` already return promises).

```
module.exports.getAllStatisticsByUserId = function(id, callback){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) =>{
            if(err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(user.statistics);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: According to [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) (assumed based on the use of `findById()`), simply omitting the callback parameter causes the function to return an object that implements `.then()` already, so there's no need to wrap either of them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think Dan is correct to wrap them since the question is about callback-style code in general rather than Mongoose methods specifically.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How do we know that `findById` means Mongoose? Could be [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findById), could be a custom model class.

Comment: @DanPrince true, I can remove the tag (and probably should now that you point that out), but my comment still stands. Sequelize also returns a promise as you can see there, as would virtually any up-to-date database API on npm.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Probably, but it doesn't help anyone who's trying to learn when we land assumptions on them. For all we know, the asker wrote the `findById` method themselves.

Comment: I hope you understand I'm not telling you to edit your answer. If I had, I would have said so.

Comment: Sure I know. I'm just trying to make sure the answers here are as general as possible, so that people learn how to solve the problem in all cases.